# php- check 2 elements same and find sum

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON returned from the backend service.

```
$a='{
    "post_id": [
        "1",
        "34",
        "29",
        "35",
        "28",
        "37"
    ],
    "posted_by": [
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "3"
    ],
    "total_likes": [
        4,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    ]
}';
```

JSON has post_id, posted_by and how many likes a post received.
I convert it into array for processing in php

```
$data   =   json_decode($a);
```

My array looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [post_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 34
            [2] => 29
            [3] => 35
            [4] => 28
            [5] => 37
        )

    [posted_by] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 3
        )

    [total_likes] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 1
        )

)
```

`posted_by` is user. and what I'm trying to do is to find how many likes a user received and save that value in a new array. SO, in this case, user 1 received 8 likes and user 3 received 1 like. And,I have to save this in an array.

So, for achieving that, I tried something like this but I didn't get any results. Undefined offset error is shown when the loop executes for the nth time.

```
$total_likes=0;
        $data2=array();

        for($j=0; $j<sizeof($data['posted_by']);$j++)
        {
            if($data['posted_by'][$j] == $data['posted_by'][$j+1])
            {
                $data2[$j]['user']      =   $data['posted_by'][$j];
                $data2[$j]['likes']     =   $total_likes + $data['total_likes'][$j];
            }

        }
```

Is there any built in function to do such a check?

Comment: use it as `$data   =   json_decode($a,TRUE);` to make it associative array as you use in your code.Othrewise it  returned objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomand something like this :

```
$data = json_decode($a);
// list of all user sid
$users = array_unique($data['posted_by']);
$listUserLike = [];

foreach($users as $user) {
    $indexes = array_keys($data['posted_by'], $user);
    $likes = array_intersect_key($data['total_likes'], array_flip($indexes));
    $listUserLike[] = ['user' => $user, 'nbLike' => array_sum($likes)];
}
```

then you would have all the results in $listUserLike

listUserLike = [
   ['user' => 1, 'nbLike' => 8],
   ['user' => 3, 'nbLike' => 1],
]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cnt = 0;
$temp = array();
$newArr = array();
foreach($data['posted_by'] as $user) {
    if(in_array($user, $temp)) {
        $newArr[$user] = $newArr[$user] + $data['total_likes'][$cnt];
    } else {
        $temp[$user] = $user;
        $newArr[$user] = $data['total_likes'][$cnt];
    }
    $cnt++;
}
print '<pre>';print_r($newArr);
exit;
```